# Lookup parent_id name and render it in HTML

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a simple `index.html.haml` view that will show all books for sale and their location. The location is placed inside a small tag that will show the city where the book is being sold:

```
%small
    #{book.location.name.titleize}
```

above code shows the name of the city selected.

What I would like to see is the State and the City like this:

`State Name > City Name`

My `Location` table is very simple with an: `id`, `name` and a `parent_id`. In my model, I referenced the table to itself by:

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :books
belongs_to :parent_location, class_name: Location
has_many :child_locations, class_name: Location, foreign_key: "parent_id"
end
```

Is there a function that will lookup the name of the parent location of the city?

Comment: If I understand correctly the city is `book.location`, then city's parent location would be `book.location.parent_location`

Comment: I'm getting an undefined method error. But I get the concept and I'll try to work around it thanks! Btw in my books table, what's being saved is the location_id not the name which is why I had to add `.name` in there. Maybe that's why I'm getting an error?

Comment: `book.location` gives you an instance of the `Location` class that represents the location with the id of the location_id saved in the books table.  So the error you get. Does it say no method error for Location?

Comment: I was trying to put a `.name` at the end which gives me `undefined method id' for nil:NilClass` but when I removed it, and just did `book.location.parent_location` the index view ran but nothing was returned in the space provided for the city. It's just blank.

Comment: Looks like you have to add a foreign key option to your belongs to method. `belongs_to :parent_location, class_name: Location, foreign_key: 'parent_id'`

Comment: Is it legal to summarize your answer in the "Post your Answer" box and make it official so I can tag it as answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure you include a foreign key option in your belongs to definition because the association name is different from your foreign key "parent_id":

```
belongs_to :parent_location, class_name: Location, foreign_key: 'parent_id'
```

Then you can get the parent location of the city like this:

```
book.location.parent_location
```